# Как сделать плавную смену картинки onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать плавную смену картинки на onmouseover?

```css
#mycloud {width:100%;} 
#mycloud div, img, p{cursor: pointer;}
#mycloud img{ width:150px;padding:3px;background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #777;}    
#mycloud img:hover{border:2px solid #222;margin:-1px;}
```

```html
<div id="mycloud">
  <img id="opacity1" data-onclick="3" onmouseout="this.src='img/small/3.jpg'" onmouseover="this.src='img/small/4.jpg'" src="img/small/3.jpg">
  <img data-onclick="4" onmouseout="this.src='img/small/3.jpg'" onmouseover="this.src='img/small/4.jpg'" src="img/small/4.jpg">
  <img data-onclick="5" onmouseout="this.src='img/small/3.jpg'" onmouseover="this.src='img/small/4.jpg'" src="img/small/5.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать на css - для внешнего div'а создаём псевдо-элементы с изображениями. Внутри div'a уже ничего не нужно:

```
#mycloud {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  position: relative;
}
#mycloud:before,
#mycloud:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, visibility 0.5s linear;
}
#mycloud:before {
  background: url(img/small/3.jpg);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#mycloud:after {
  background: url(img/small/4.jpg);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#mycloud:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#mycloud:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Пример тут http://jsbin.com/zawolamaqe/edit?html,css,output